# Equivalent of Latable for matrix/vectors generation

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays, editors

Does anyone know an equivalent for [Latable](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/support/latable/) (which is used to generate latex code for tables) but to do the same thing with matrices and arrays ?

Comment: Latable can create `array`s at least.

Comment: Agree, but not flexible to obtain matrices and vectors { http://www.math-linux.com/latex-26/faq/latex-faq/How-to-write-matrices-in-Latex }

Answer (score 1):

The array wizards in Texmaker and TeXstudio both allow you generate the various `matrix` environments from `amsmath`. In both editors, go to Wizard(s) --> Quick Array. In the *environment* dropdown you can choose from `array`, `matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `vmatrix` and `Vmatrix`.

Screenshots from TeXstudio:

[image]

[image]